# Why are knights titled "Ser" in Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the books and literature following the Game of Thrones universe a knight's title is spelled with an 'e' not an 'i' for "S**e**r". Why is this?

Comment: See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85629/ for a similar question.

Comment: For another fantasy reference, Stephen Donaldson's collection "Daughter of Regals" includes a short story called "Ser Visal's Tale". As with the other sources, "Ser" is an honorific.

Comment: Actually it would probably be Modern English still, which has been spoke since before Shakespeare. Perhaps Middle English, the language of Chaucer, but definitely not Old English, which is a very different language than the Modern English we speak today.

Answer (score 31):

**George RR Martin** has a penchant for introducing things in his universe which resemble those in ours, yet have a different texture to them. This lets the user relate to those "*words*" better and at the same time renders them an exotic and enigmatic aura.

That's the reason *Sir* becomes *Ser*, *Master* becomes *Maester*. The same can also be observed in the way he names people. *Rob* is *Robb* and *Edward* is *Eddard*.

All these are mere ploys to create an enchanting but understandable world!

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Opinion or fact? If fact, are there any references to show that this is intentional on the part of the author?

Comment: @CGCampbell: I seriously doubt that GRRM has made these changes _unintentionally_. However, I failed to find any material on the web where he explicitly mentions his reason behind this usage.

Comment: Considering that Meister is the modern German, it's not such a stretch that old anglo-saxon was either Meister or Maester. Also, before dictionaries canonized language, spelling was kind of ah, fluid.

Answer (score 19):

Ser is used in other fantasy works as well. It's a gender neutral title. It's possible ser is an older version of sir (like many words that have changed over time) so ser would be the correct spelling for the period.

> Noun ser (plural sers)
>
> (used in some fantasy novels) An address or courtesy title to any
>   person, especially if their gender and/or form of address are unknown.
>    Example: Would ser care to dine this evening?

[Source](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ser#English)

You can also google search to find the many different works that use 'Ser'. Just think, "Old English".

Comment: Or just think, "Olde English". ;-)

Comment: As per the comment above, it's unlikely to be **Old** English.  That is the language of Beowulf, and it is a Germanic language, but mutually unintelligible with Modern English (which is what Shakespeare wrote). "Ðunor cymð of hætan & of wætan. Seo lyft tyhð þone wætan to hire neoðan & ða hætan ufan.’ (Word for word translation = "Thunder comes from heat and from moisture. The air draws the moisture to it from below and the heat from above.")